# Highcharts, how to use gradient without setting a color?

Tags: highcharts

I'm looking to set a gradient color for my graph area's where the color goes from it's "default" color to white/transparent.

I'm working how can I "Choose" not set a value and let it auto decide the area color.

This is what my code is producting now: 
[image of my graph now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UXAS6.png)

(I'm looking to match the fill color to the "outline" color that's auto set)

Code that's being used to set this "yellow-ish color" right now

```
        linearGradient: {
          x1: 0,
          y1: 0,
          x2: 0,
          y2: 1
        },
        stops: [
          [0, "#ffff00"],
          [
            1,
            Highcharts.color("#DADADA")
              .setOpacity(0)
              .get("rgba")
          ]
        ]
      },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `getOptions` method to get the default color and set it in this way:

```
series: [{
  ...,
  fillColor: {
    linearGradient: {
      x1: 0,
      y1: 0,
      x2: 0,
      y2: 1
    },
    stops: [
      [0, Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]],
      [1, Highcharts.color(Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]).setOpacity(0).get('rgba')]
    ]
  }
}, ...]
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/6m4e8x0y/4910/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts#.getOptions